# Как проигрывать аудио(mp3) и обновлять seekBar Android, Java

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Как проигрывать аудио(mp3) и обновлять `seekBar`, на Java.
И ещё по возможности подскажите, как перематывать аудио с помощью того же `seekBar`

Плеер  (три кнопки и `seekBar`) я создал в отдельном фрагменте.

Comment: покажите как вы сделали свой `seekbar`

Comment: Вот тут если не лень можете поковырять мою реализацию: [тык](https://github.com/mohaxspb/Odnako/blob/v3.0/src/ru/kuchanov/odnako/fragments/FragmentDialogEasterEggMusic.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        final TextView labelTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelTxt);
        labelTxt.setText("Playing word...");

        final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a042);

        try {
            mPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mPlayer.seekTo(62085); // Это откуда начать воспроизводить
        mPlayer.start();

        // Тут создем цикл для проверки куда дошли     
        mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                while(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    // Если нужно где то остановить, можем это тоже управлять
                    if(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() >  65436 ){
                        labelTxt.setText("Stop: " + mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() );
                        mPlayer.stop();
                        break;
                    }
                // ---------------------------------
                // Тут можно менять значения seekbar
                // ---------------------------------
                }
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: Выдает ексепшн Cannot create AudioDevice :с

Comment: @ЯрославМовчан библиотеки все добавили?

Comment: `jLayer` от Javazoom, больше ничего. Я добавил только Jar.